# Convert from arbitrary dates to single date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've been asked to migrate data from one table to another. The old data includes a series of dates entered in a mishmash of whatever format the user felt like using at the time, the new format requires separate FROM date and TO date fields in MM/YYYY.

So some dates are a single date, such as DD.MM.YYYY or DD/MM/YY or DD YYYY or YYYY or again whatever. Some dates are both dates, such as DD.MM.YYYY-DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YY--DD/MM/YYYY. So just a mess. There are only a couple hundred rows but I don't feel like going through and changing them manually if I can avoid it.

Most of the Google results are for converting one format to another format, how can I convert from a mess of formats to one?

Comment: Normalization can take lots of work.  I'd try to see how many different patterns you can identify.  Some will be easy, some will be hard.  Some will have to be done by hand.   Once you know what patterns/formats are used, you can use `strtotime()` to convert to something sensible like a unix time stamp that you can then display later in whatever format you need/want.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: DD YYYY? Really? There is no real way to know if `06 11 12` is sixth of November or if it's the eleventh of June, or even something else. No code in the world can parse all the different formats humans can make up.

Comment: I meant MM not DD in that case sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single expression to encompass all combinations is hard so just do the patterns one by one:

```
UPDATE olddata,newdata
SET newdata.date=STR_TO_DATE(olddate.date, "%d.%m.%Y")
WHERE olddata.id=newdata.id
  AND olddata.date REGEXP '[:digit:]{1,2}\.[:digit:]{1,2}.[:digit:]{4}'
  AND newdata.date IS NULL
```

Do this a multiple times for each date format, and use the right expression in [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Experiment selecting with the right regulate expression before doing the update.

Eventually you'll have enough record to edit manually

Comment: This is the right answer. Add conversions for all specific until you have very little (or none) left to do manually +++

Comment: So I didn't use MYSQL because I don't have enough experience with it, so I did pretty much what you said but in PHP.

Comment: Should of mentioned for testing  the regex/str_to_date - `SELECT date, STR_TO_DATE(date, "%d.%m.%Y") FROM olddata WHERE date REGEXP '[:digit:]{1,2}\.[:digit:]{1,2}.[:digit:]{4}'` to see the matches/conversions where sane.